# MATLAB vision.TextInserter does not insert text

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

[image]

I am trying to insert text message into an image. It does not display and I get no error.

```
close all
clear all
clc

hVideoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer;
hVideoFileReader = vision.VideoFileReader;
hVideoFileReader.Filename = 'img1.jpg';

frame = step(hVideoFileReader);


hcsc = vision.ColorSpaceConverter;
hcsc.Conversion = 'RGB to intensity';
frame = step(hcsc, frame);

at = vision.Autothresholder;
frame = step(at, frame);


ccl = vision.ConnectedComponentLabeler;
[L NUM] = step(ccl, frame);

holeObjCount = 0;

for i=1:NUM
    framei = changem(L==i, 1, i);

    framei = imcomplement(framei);

    [Li NUMi] = step(ccl, framei);

    if NUMi > 1
        holeObjCount = holeObjCount + 1;
    end

end

message = sprintf('%d of %d objects have holes.', holeObjCount, NUM);
disp(message);

osdMsg = vision.TextInserter('%d of %d objects have holes.',... 
                             'Color', uint8([255, 255, 255]), ...
                             'Location', [10 10],...
                             'FontSize', 22);
%The problem is here
frame = step(osdMsg, frame, int32([holeObjCount NUM]));

step(hVideoPlayer, frame); 

release(hVideoFileReader);

release(hVideoPlayer);
```

The problem is because of color space of the image. I have attempted to display a RGB colored text on a B/W image which can not show natutally.

After removing color attribute, I could see the text

```
osdMsg = vision.TextInserter('%d of %d objects have holes.',... 
                             'Location', [10 10],...
                             'FontSize', 22);
```

The problem is now, the text inserted is black and cannot be read clearly.

Comment: What is the step function? Because AFAIK it is this one:http://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/step.html and it definetly is not used as/for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Apologies I end up finding the `step` for videoPlayer. But the (very short) docs seem to indicate that only 2 inputs are accepted.http://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.videoplayer.step.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that after thresholding `frame` is a logical array. To make the text show up use `im2uint8` to convert it to `uint8`.

A few other pointers: since you are working with a single image rather than with a video you can use `imread` instead of `vision.VideoFileReader` to read it in. You can also use `imshow` instead of `vision.VideoPlayer` for the same reason. Also, if you have MATLAB version R2013a or later, you can use the `insertText` function instead of `vision.TextInserter`.

Comment: `im2uint8()` is what I need.. But eventhough I set color of the text to red `'Color', uint8([255, 0, 0]),...` it still displays white text.

Comment: For that, you need to make your image RGB: `frame = cat(3, frame, frame, frame)`.  Better yet, use `insertText()` if you can, because it will do that for you.